# Fully transparent CupertinoNavigationBar possible?

Tags: flutter

I am using a `CupertinoTabScaffold` with a couple of `CupertinoTabView`s and `CupertinoPageScaffold`s.

This is my setup:

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
   navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   ),
   child: ...
)
```

The problem is that I want a large header image which extends behind the navigation bar. According to the Flutter docs the background gets a blurry effect once the backgroundColor has some transparency.

So I cannot find a way to make this navigation bar completely transparent.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: You can use stack or make AppBar looks like cupertino app bar

Answer (score 2):

```
class _DetailWebViewControllerState extends State<DetailWebViewController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),),
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: widget.url,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ));
  }
}
```

this gets me a transparent NavigationBar but I still have a thin line at the bottom of the navigation bar which makes it unusable. I still havent found how to get rid of it.

Comment: This doesn't work either, it just produces a blurred (yet indeed transparent) navigation bar, so not completely what the OP is looking for. FWIW, the thin line at the bottom of the bar is the border. You can hide this by setting the `border` property on CupertinoNavigationBar. `border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent)` should work for you.

Comment: Set `border: Border()` to remove border from `CupertinoNavigationBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a SpecialColor

```
class SpecialColor extends Color {
  const SpecialColor() : super(0x00000000);

  @override
  int get alpha => 0xFF;
}
```

Use it like

```
CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
      largeTitle: Text("title"),
      backgroundColor: const SpecialColor(),
);
```

The reason is that the CupertinoSliderNavigationBar will determine `alpha==0xFF`, and if it is true, there will be no blur effect attached

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the backgroundColor to null  ?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker/backgroundColor.html

you could also try the following

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3255068-quaternarysystemfill

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
   navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
     backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.quaternarySystemFill,
   ),
   child: ...
)
```

UPDATE: 
This is not working, tested in my application and came out negative